# how to add Columns to a table by performing aggregate function on the field of other function?

Tags: c#, database, sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions

table schema of tables is as follows :
1) MainTable(Date,CC,BU,Amount,Mode)
2) Table2(Date,CC,BU,column1,column2,column3,column4)

here,
for Table2

column1 = select SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE CC= 'value1' and Mode LIKE '011';
column2 = select SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE CC= 'value1' and Mode LIKE '012';
column3 = select SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE CC= 'value1' and Mode LIKE '10_';
column4 = select SUM(Amount) from MainTable WHERE CC= 'value1' and Mode LIKE '03_';
Date = Date value from MainTable

I managed to get the values for column1,column2,column3,column4 
but How to get values for Date1 for those aggregated function.

please help me!!! thank you in advance!!!

Comment: You want which record's Date?Can You be more specific so that i can answer your problem

Comment: As a comment - I'm not positive but if you are doing an exact match use an equals sign (=) instead of like. When you do Like '011' it's essentially saying = '011' and I think equals is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You would group by date...

example:
column1 = select Date, SUM(Amount) from MainTable GROUP BY Date HAVING CC= 'value1' and Mode LIKE '011';